# Flutter error : Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

When i add the following code i get an error

W/Firestore(10073): (23.0.4) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(exc order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match  /exc/{uid}/{document=**}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

```
.
..
...
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: _buildContents(context),
              ),
            ],
          ),
...


Widget _buildContents(BuildContext context) {
  final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
  return StreamBuilder<List<Profile>>(
    stream: database.profilesStream(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final profiles = snapshot.data;
        final children =
            profiles.map((profile) => Text(profile.nickname)).toList();
        return ListView(children: children);
      }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  );
}
```

This is my database.dart that i use

```
abstract class Database {
  Future<void> createProfile(Profile profile);
  Stream<List<Profile>> profilesStream();
}

class FirestoreDatabase implements Database {
  FirestoreDatabase({@required this.uid}) : assert(uid != null);
  final String uid;

  Future<void> createProfile(Profile profile) => _setData(
        path: APIPath.profile(uid, 'profile_abc'),
        data: profile.toMap(),
      );

  Stream<List<Profile>> profilesStream() {
    final path = APIPath.profiles(uid);
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map(
          (snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.data();
            return data != null
                ? Profile(
                    nickname: data['nickname'],
                    birthday: data['birthday'],
                  )
                : null;
          },
        ));
  }

  Future<void> _setData({String path, Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    print('$path: $data');
    await reference.set(data);
  }
}
```

```
class APIPath {
  static String profile(String uid, String profileId) => 'exc/$uid/';
  static String profiles(String uid) => 'exc/$uid/profiles';
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have created a collection in firebase?

Comment: What's the name in Firebase your are using for your profile collection? /profile? And how to you try to fetch it in database.profilesStream()?

Comment: I have created a collection in Firebase. I have edited the code above and added more info